# average using SUM and dividing by non-empty count with MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

I know this should be easy but I'm new to MDX and having trouble getting it right.  My goal is to get the average order cost for a specific customer, including the customer's sub-accounts in the hierarchy.  I can get the average correctly using the MDX below if I wanted to count zero-dollar orders but I don't (they actually show up as empty, not zero, but don't worry about that).  So how do I update the query so that it only looks at non-empty OrderCost values?  The last line was a failed attempt.

```
WITH MEMBER avgcost as ([Measures].[OrderCost]/[Measures].[OrderCount])
SELECT avgcost on columns,
[Dim User].[User ID].&[381] on rows
from [OrdersCube]
//where Filter([Dim User].[User ID].All, [Measures].[OrderCost].Value <> "")
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the `Avg()` function? It ignores empty cells by default. You'll need to construct a set that describes the individual orders that you want averaged (and not the aggregated OrderCost for the one user). For example:

```
WITH MEMBER avgcost as Avg([Orders].Members, [Measures].[OrderCost])
SELECT 
    avgcost on columns,
    [Dim User].[User ID].&[381] on rows
from [OrdersCube]
```

See documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146067.aspx